# Is debugging a machine learning algorithm on-topic here?

Tags: discussion

I was voting to close [this question which is off-topic on programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324683/cant-find-the-error-with-gradient-descent-function) and was wondering whether or not it would be considered on-topic here (in the end I decided to play it safe and recommend stackoverflow, where it definitely is on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

I suppose it depends on whether the problem is likely to do with the programming of the implementation, or whether the idea being implemented is incorrect as an algorithm. The latter is on-topic here, I'd say.

Comment: I would actually argue that either is on-topic. Programming an ML algorithm (sometimes from scratch) is both an important and useful way to learn ML/DS.